# I'm getting a "Connection unexpectedly closed" whenever I try to send an email with django hosted with Cloud Run. How do I diagnose this?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

In my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend
EMAIL_HOST = smtp-relay.gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

the line that actually sends the mail in one of the api end points is

```
send_mail(subject, body, email_from, recipient_list)
```

I can confirm with logs that the user and password is correct. I also can confirm that this works locally when I run it on my local environment. The issue is when I deploy this via Google Cloud Run I'm just getting `Connection unexpectedly closed` with no stacktrace and no information.

From the Networking tab in cloud run I have allowed all ingress and have not set up any VPC network so I don't think it's that, however because of the nature of containerizing my app I don't know what else it could really be.

What else would you try to diagnose and search?

Comment: I'm no longer encountering the issue. I think what happened was I called the IT of the SMTP server and asked them if they were blacklisting my requests from Cloud Run. They never got back to me but ever since that call it started working so I'm guessing they whitelisted me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no longer encountering the issue. I think what happened was I called the IT of the SMTP server and asked them if they were blacklisting my requests from Cloud Run. They never got back to me but ever since that call it started working so I'm guessing they whitelisted me

Comment: Please make sure to mark your own answer as correct if you solved your problem.